# Handling Null Pointers from JsonReader

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, jsonreader

I am using JsonReader to fetch lots of data from a website and saving to a db. Incidentally, whenever the reader doesnt find a value for an object item, it fails and stops executing.

This is the error i have;

```
System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was NULL at line 1 column 359337 path $[19].date
```

Even if the specified value is not available, it seems all objects loaded before the error was encountered are lost too and are not saved to the db. Is there a way to handle these errors and keep the objects that had been loaded so far? I have set JsonReader as lenient.

This is the part of the method that parses the data:

```
private Post read(JsonReader reader) throws Exception {
            reader.beginObject();

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String name = reader.nextName();

                switch (name) {
                    case TITLE:
                        mTitle = new StringBuilder();
                        mTitle.append(reader.nextString());
                        break;
                    case AUTHOR:
                        if (reader.hasNext()) {
                            JsonToken peek = reader.peek();

                            if (peek == JsonToken.NULL) {
                                reader.skipValue();
                            } else {
                                reader.beginObject();

                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    String enclosedName = reader.nextName();

                                    switch (enclosedName) {
                                        case NAME:
                                            mAuthor = new StringBuilder();
                                            mAuthor.append(reader.nextString());
                                            break;
                                        case AVATAR:
                                            mAvatar = new StringBuilder();
                                            mAvatar.append(reader.nextString());
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            reader.skipValue();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }

                                reader.endObject();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case CONTENT:
                        mDescription = new StringBuilder();
                        mDescription.append(reader.nextString());
                        break;
                    case URL:
                        mEntryLink = new StringBuilder();
                        mEntryLink.append(reader.nextString());
                        break;
                    case DATE:
                        mDateStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        mDateStringBuilder.append(reader.nextString());
                        break;
                    case GUID:
                        mGuid = new StringBuilder();
                        mGuid.append(reader.nextString());
                        break;
                    case FEATURED_IMAGE:
                        if (reader.hasNext()) {
                            JsonToken look = reader.peek();

                            if (look == JsonToken.NULL) {
                                reader.skipValue();
                            } else {
                                mFeaturedImage = new StringBuilder();
                                reader.beginObject();

                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    String itemToLookFor = reader.nextName();

                                    switch (itemToLookFor) {
                                        case SOURCE:
                                            mFeaturedImage.append(reader.nextString());
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            reader.skipValue();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }

                                reader.endObject();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case TERMS:
                        if (reader.hasNext()) {
                            JsonToken check = reader.peek();

                            if (check == JsonToken.NULL) {
                                reader.skipValue();
                            } else {
                                reader.beginObject();

                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    String stuff = reader.nextName();

                                    switch (stuff) {
                                        case CATEGORIES:
                                            reader.beginArray();

                                            itemCategory = new StringBuilder();

                                            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                                reader.beginObject();

                                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                                    String item = reader.nextName();

                                                    switch (item) {
                                                        case NAME:
                                                            itemCategory.append(reader.nextString()).append(",");
                                                            break;
                                                        default:
                                                            reader.skipValue();
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                reader.endObject();
                                            }
                                            reader.endArray();
                                            break;
                                        case TAGS:
                                            reader.beginArray();

                                            itemTags = new StringBuilder();

                                            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                                reader.beginObject();

                                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                                    String item = reader.nextName();

                                                    switch (item) {
                                                        case NAME:
                                                            itemTags.append(reader.nextString()).append(",");
                                                            break;
                                                        default:
                                                            reader.skipValue();
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                reader.endObject();
                                            }
                                            reader.endArray();
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            reader.skipValue();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }

                                reader.endObject();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        reader.skipValue();
                        break;
                }
            }

            reader.endObject();

            return new Post(mAuthor.toString(), mAvatar.toString(), mDateStringBuilder.toString(), mTitle.toString(), mEntryLink.toString(), mDescription.toString(), mGuid.toString(), mFeaturedImage.toString(), itemTags.toString(), itemCategory.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Please supply the code that you are working with

Comment: @Knossos check updated question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought may be you weren't checking for `NULL` elements, that seems to be the case.

At one point you use:

```
JsonToken check = reader.peek();

if (check == JsonToken.NULL) {
```

That is correct. However, in other places you simply get the `String`:

```
mDescription.append(reader.nextString());
```

In all places you are getting a `String`, you need to check whether there is actually an unexpected type (such as `NULL`). In cases like this, you need to apply appropriate error containment code.

Incidentally, you really don't need to be creating all of those `StringBuilder`s. Since you are only putting one `String` into it after each initialization. You would save a lot of time by simply using a String. If you intend to write all the contents to a `StringBuilder` for each type, then you need to initialize them before you start looping.